# Symfony, Doctrine, merge not working properly (while persist of the same entity does)

Tags: php, symfony, inheritance, doctrine

I am kind of confused with the behaviour of Symfony/Doctrine.

I have a form that, when submit, sends back data to a controller. This controller checks, if the form holds data of a new entity or of one that already has an id in the database (which was loaded into the form before):

```
if ($form->isValid()) {
            if ($sup->getId() > 0) {
                return $this->editUserAction($sup);
            } else {
                return $this->addUserAction($sup);
            }
        }
```

The two functions that are called are almost equal. They only differ in the command persist vs. merge. Interestingly, the persist writes a field that is not written when merging:

There is an inheritance:

supplier extends company,
company extends contact

ORM-wise company is a MappedSuperclass and also contact is a MappedSuperclass (both abstract). This is, because a supplier is a specialization of a company, which again is already a specialization of a generic contact.

All values from supplier directly and the ones inherited from contact are written to the database (always).
All values only coming from company are written to the database when persist is called but never when merge is called. There is no overridden property in those classes.

It's the same form that sends data (created a FormType for this: TypeSupplier). It is the same classes etc. Getters and setters are defined (otherwise the form could not set the values for persisting). Even if I enter the same data, once from scratch and once changing another entity.

And one more point: The value in the database is not overwritten with null. It just does not change while all other values will change on merge.

Not sure if this information helps: The debugger in phpStorm shows that the value is set in the variable $sup in the line where merge is called: "Whizzpm\Bundle\Entity\Contact\Company*name1 = "Test value"

```
public function addUserAction(Supplier $sup)
{

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $em->perist($sup);
    $em->flush();

    return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('suppliers_show'));
}

public function editUserAction(Supplier $sup)
{

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $em->merge($sup);
    $em->flush();

    return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('suppliers_show'));
}
```

Here is an extract of the entity class company with the two values that are not written to the database when merge is called:

```
/**
 * Class Company
 * @package Whizzpm\Bundle\Entity\Contact
 * @ORM\MappedSuperclass
 */
abstract class Company extends Contact {
    /**
     * @var string
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=60, nullable=false)
     */
    private $name1;
    /**
     * @var string
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=60, nullable=true)
     */
    private $name2;

    /**
     * @var integer
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", name="employees", nullable=true)
     */
```

Does anybody have an idea or any resource I can check for help here? Can't find anything specific on the net. Only general information on merge and persist.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why it did not work by merge but I took another path:

- Fetch the entitiy by id which was posted by the form
- Then update this id with the form data ($form->handleRequest($request)
- Persist the updated entity to the database

Here's the resulting code (I skipped the extra function addUserAction/editUserAction, since both works in one shot now:

```
public function showSuppliersAction(Request $request)
{
    $sup = null;
    if($supplier = $request->request->get('supplier')) {
        if(isset($supplier['id'])) {
            $sup = $this->getDoctrine()
                ->getRepository('WhizzpmBundle:Supplier\Supplier')
                ->findOneById($supplier['id']);
        }
    }

    if(!$sup) {
        $sup = new Supplier();
    }

    $form = $this->createForm(new SupplierType(), $sup);

    $form->handleRequest($request);

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    if ($form->isValid()) {
        $em->persist($sup);
        $em->flush();
    }

    // ....
}
```

Comment: Since I got no answers within a week I will just accept my own answer, since it solved my problem.